# input type date is showing time when added in database

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to the programming world most specially to angular(front-end) and c#(back-end).

I recently bumped into a problem to one of my html input which displays time whenever I save the form.

**add-edit-pt.component.html**

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label mg-top">Delivery Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="date" class="form-control mg-top" [(ngModel)]="DateReceived">
    </div>
```

**add-edit-pt.component.ts**

```js
addPlacardTracker(){
    var val = {    
      PlacardTrackerId:this.PlacardTrackerId,
      DateReceived:this.DateReceived,
    };
    this.service.addPlacardTracker(val).subscribe(res=>{alert(res.toString());
  });
  }
```

**Here is the sample screenshot:**

[image: Table with date input showing time]

The strange thing is that, I have the same identical form and structure (different variable) in my other page and they are not showing any time.

[image: Table with date input not showing time]

Hope anyone here can help me as I already exhaust my resources and I cannot find any answer.

Comment: The million dollar question is: what's the type in the database? And I guess the other question is: how is it getting to the frontend?

Comment: The type in database is set as date, just like the other tables that are not showing time.

I have a shared.service.ts for the connection of API to Angular which has the code of 

`export class SharedService {
readonly APIUrl="https://localhost:4000/api";

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) { }

  getPlacardTrackerList():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/placardtracker');
  }

  addPlacardTracker(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/placardtracker',val);
  }
`

And the above very top codes are how it is being pushed in the back-end

Comment: If that's SQL Server then the `Date` column datatype doesn't store a time component. You'll probably want `datetime2` for that. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi Llama, thank you so much for your time. Sorry but I don't need the time in my date hehehe. Sql datatype is already set as Date but whenever I save my (html date picker) in my form, it is saving as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss . I want my form to not show time huhuhu